# Saving "PDF File" output from GET DOCUMENT REST API Call Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am having challenges saving the "PDF File" result from a GET Document REST API call in Docusign. I can obtain the 'text' version of the pdf file both using the Developer Center:API Explorer, as well as in POSTMAN and, in my Power Automate flow. I receive a long file of characters starting with

```
"%PDF-1.7\n%����\n%Writing objects...\n4 0 obj\n
```

and ending in

```
n229500\n%%EOF"
```

It appears similar to other PDF files that I converted to .txt to view the raw content.

However, when I take the "pdf file" from either Docusign API Explorer or POSTMAN and copy it to say NOTEPAD and save the file as .pdf......the document will not open.

I am sure this is a simple issue but scouring the Docusign developer FAQ's, and other web resources has yet to reveal the issue I am having and hoping for a quick answer here.

Comment: PDF is not a text file, it's binary. 
Notepad is a text editor, not a hex/binary editor.
You need to use your code and save a binary stream to file.

Comment: That is perfect. That has helped nudge me in the right direction. I have now been able to resolve the issue by taking this approach.

Comment: I put this as an answer then, please mark it as resolved; Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF is not a text file, it's binary. Notepad is a text editor, not a hex/binary editor. You need to use your code and save a binary stream to file.